# Troubleshooting Integration Issues with One tap Google Sign-In Button on a Website

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-oauth, google-signin

As part of a university assignment, I've been attempting to integrate the One Tap Google Sign-In button into a website. Initially, the button was not functioning properly on a local server via Visual Studio Code. To troubleshoot, I deployed my project on GitHub Pages, which slightly improved the situation. However, a significant issue persists: on the first click, the account selection window appears, and after choosing an account, it only shows a loading screen without further progress. Subsequent attempts to click the button result in a loading screen without the account selection option, leading to no further action. Below, I will attach screenshots of my configuration in the Google Console and the relevant code snippets for further insight. I really need professional help. Thanks in advance for your answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="my_id_here"/>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <title>Prihlásenie pomocou Google API</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Sign in:</p>
      <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

        console.log('Úplné meno: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Meno: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Priezvisko: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Obrázok profilu: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        let id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);

        document.querySelector("#content").innerHTML = "<p>Hello " + profile.getGivenName() + "! Click to <a href='#' onclick='signOut();'>sign out</a>.</p>";
      }

      function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
          alert("err");
          location.reload();
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html
```

in google console to Ouath 2 all that i write
Authorized JavaScript origins - https://{here-nick-name}.github.io
Authorized redirect URIs - the sae link